# Add images to colorbox jquery

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have used color box for showing list of images. and its working fine for pre-loaded images.

but my problem is how can i add image uploaded by jquery in colorbox popup dynamically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you posted your code here, otherwise we can only guess. The problem might be that you called the `colorbox()` function when the HTML was loaded. But please be aware that the colorbox function must be called (again) once the process of loading further images via AJAX is complete, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    /* AJAX options go here */
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $('.ajax-images').colorbox(); /* Define the colorboxes for the new content */
});
```

Comment: Its not ajax call. am trying to apply colorbox event after cropping image by image crop.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are doing - uploading, cropping? Like you said, you would have to call the `colorbox` function once the corresponding elements were added to the DOM

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was looking at all the dynamic loading of images and hooking colorbox to those on Stack and this was what finally worked, Straight forward and simple.